Two types of definitions of the distance function
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain, $n \ge 2$. I'm wondering that for any
$x \in \Omega$, do we have
$$
   \text{dist}(x,\partial \Omega) = \text{dist}(x, \Omega^c)? 
$$
It seems natural. Any idea will be helpful. Thanks in advance.
On the one direction, since $\partial \Omega \subset \Omega^c$, we have
$$
\text{dist}(x,\Omega^c) \leq \text{dist}(x,\partial \Omega). 
$$
On the other direction, we have
$\Omega^c = (\Omega^c)^\circ \cap \partial \Omega.$
If $y_0 \in  (\Omega^c)^\circ$, such that
$d(y_0,x) = \text{dist}(x,\Omega^c) $. Then there must exist another point such that $d(y_1,x) < d(y_0,x)$ (just pick a point in the line between $y_0$ and $x$). Therefore, the infimum should be taken in $\partial \Omega$.

Beware, you don't have $\partial \Omega \subset \Omega^c$ because what if $\Omega$ is closed. You have that $\partial \Omega \subset Adh(\Omega^c)$ but the reasoning still works because $d(x,\Omega) = d(x,Adh(\Omega))$

@anton domain is a non-empty, connected and open set.

For starters I suppose, you meant to write $\Omega^C=\left(\Omega^C\right)^O\cup\partial\Omega$. Now, regarding this part of your proof:

Then there must exist another point such that $d(y_1,x) < d(y_0,x)$ (just pick a point in the line between $y_0$ and $x$). Therefore, the infimum should be taken in $\partial \Omega$.

You made a small mistake, but it's a quick fix. After constructing a line, $l$ , between $x$ and $y_0$, you should get an intersection between $l$ and $\partial \Omega$, which we can name $y$. And then pick a point between $y$ and $y_0$, instead of picking a point between $x$ and $y_0$ (since point between $x$ and $y_0$ can be in $\Omega$ and then the infimum would be $d(x,x)=0$). Meaning $d(x,y_0)>d(x,y_1)\ge dist(x,\Omega^C)$, therefore a contradiction since you assumed $d(x,y_0)=dist(x,\Omega^C)$.

I omit a detail that since $y_0 \in (\Omega^c)^\circ$. Therefore, there must exist a point in the line between $x$ and $y_0$, and belonging to $\Omega^c$. (Just use the definition of interior point.)

There is a difference between connected and convex, so my first thought wouldn't be to take a line between $x$ and $y_0$ as this is a characterization of convex sets. You can have really weird connected sets. Not saying that it wouldn't work, but it is a slippery road.
Take $y \in \partial \Omega$ and $z \in \Omega^c$
You have $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$
Then:
$\inf_{y \in \partial \Omega} \in d(x,y) \leq \inf_{y \in \partial \Omega}\left( d(x,z)+d(z,y)\right)$
$d(x, \partial \Omega)  \leq d(x,z)+\inf_{y \in \partial \Omega}d(z,y)$
$\inf_{z \in \Omega^c} d(x, \partial \Omega)  \leq \inf_{z \in \Omega^c}d(x,z)+\inf_{z \in \Omega^c}\inf_{y \in \partial \Omega} d(z,y)$
$d(x, \partial \Omega)  \leq d(x,\Omega^c)+\inf_{z \in \Omega^c}\inf_{y \in \partial \Omega} d(z,y)$
Now, we need to check that $\inf_{z \in \Omega^c}\inf_{y \in \partial \Omega} d(z,y) = 0$
But since you are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the euclidian distance (the usual topology) and you have a domain, I suppose it shouldn't be an issue. Use the characterization of the infimum with sequences. Or you just have as you said that $\partial \Omega \subset \Omega^c$
Notice that you don't always have $\inf_{z \in \Omega^c}\inf_{y \in \partial \Omega} d(z,y) = 0$ in any random space, for example $\mathbb{Z}$. That's why it is handy to have the definition of domain here.
